# Which loops to use for achieving time slot availability in Groovy

Tags: loops, groovy, soapui

I am trying to create booking on some time slot but i am not sure that time slot is available. So i have to check slot availability.

Step 1 : Set current start and end time to variable.
e.g : startDateTime(SDT) and endDateTime(EDT)

Step 2 : Check slot availability in DB.
e.g :

```
def res = con.firstRow("select * from tblbookingitem where active=1 and fkItemID=$roomID and DateTimeFrom=$SDT and DateTimeTo=$EDT" )
```

Step 3 : If slot not available then increment startDateTime and endDateTime in temp variable and again check DB availability

Note : this should be in loop until slot available

Step 4 : when slot is available then set to the property.

I wrote code for all the steps and only need how i achieve this using loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def isAvailable = false
def SDT = context.expand('${#Project#StartDateTime}') 
def EDT = context.expand('${#Project#EndDateTime}')
while( isAvailable==false ) 
{
//Running while loop and checking slot availability.
def res = con.firstRow("select * from tblbookingitem where active=1 and fkItemID=$roomID and DateTimeFrom='$SDT' and DateTimeTo='$EDT'" )

if(res== null) // if null that means slot is available
    {
        //Time slot is available."
        isAvailable=true; // you can use even break statment here
        context.testCase.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue('StartDateTime', SDT)
        context.testCase.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue('EndDateTime', EDT)
        log.info SDT
        log.info EDT
        break;       
    }
else
    {
        //Increment Start and End Time
        SDT=EDT
        def slotinterval = context.expand('${#Project#SlotInterval}').toInteger()
        log.info "Slot Interval : " + slotinterval

        date1 =  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'").parse(EDT)
        use(TimeCategory) 
        {
            def date2 = date1 + slotinterval.minutes
            def outputDateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
            EDT = "${date2.format(outputDateFormat)}"                       
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a for loop in below way you can achieve.

```
def flag = false

for(x=startdatetime,y=enddatetime;flag!=true  ; x++ , y++) // you can change x++ and y++ for the the way you want to increase time limit each time
{

 // check slot available
def res = con.firstRow("select * from tblbookingitem where active=1 and 
fkItemID=$roomID and DateTimeFrom=$SDT and DateTimeTo=$EDT" )

if(res!= null) // you can put the condition which says slot is available
{
 flag=true; // you can use even break statment here 
 }

 }
```

similar logic can be implemented by while loop as well with a little different syntax